# Expand clickable link within div to entire parent li (CSS only)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

**Background:**

I have created a `ul` menu that contains 2 `divs` -> one div for the icon, second div for the text. Reason for the `divs` is that I want the text to be neatly vertically aligned, which otherwise wouldn't be the case.

---

**Problem:**

I managed to make the whole second div clickable with `display: block;` but I struggle to expand the link beyond the `div` so that it stretches over the entire `li`, i.e. also covers the first `div`.

---

**Attempts:**

I already tried using Bootstrap's `.stretched-link` on the href tag (see first link) and setting `position: relative;`  to all `divs` and `li`. However, this didn't work.

---

**Question:**

Is it somehow possible to expand the link across the entire `li`, while keeping the `divs` to neatly align?

---

**Note:**

(a) I'm aware that one work-around would be to place the `href` tag around the `li`, but I understand this isn't good practice anymore.

(b) Just to show the alignment problem, I have created a second JSfiddle, when the `divs` are removed.

---

**JSfiddle**

**(1)** `divs` included, but icon `div` not clickable: https://jsfiddle.net/AlphaX/z5f60m23/11/

**(2)** `divs` removed and whole `li` is clickable, but text isn't vertically aligned because font awesome icons have different widths by default:  https://jsfiddle.net/AlphaX/89a1x7gs/2/

Comment: use SO snippet formatting instead of links, your code is a part of your question not a suplement

Comment: @blackblue I'm not sure what you mean. Could you please explain in more detail? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do your second approach, with the `<a>` wrapping the `<i>` and the `span`, and add some additional style rules:

```
li i {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I edited your Fiddle too: https://jsfiddle.net/uxnfvzyc/1/

Comment: Very neat and little invasive, fantastic! Thanks a lot Joshua!